# spring mvc [@ResourceMapping][1] get list of objects null in liferay spring MVC portlet?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay

spring mvc [@ResourceMapping][1] get list of objects null in liferay spring MVC portlet????

what's the problem?

```
 var jsonObjCommand =[{
          dc: $("#dcCode").val() ,
          question_Score : $("#101p").val() ,
          question_Desc: $("#101d").val(),
          "clinicAnalyzeQuestions.id" : 102,
          "clinicAnalyzeQuestions.questions" : 'test',
          "mobile" : $('#mobile').val(),
          "state" : $('#state').val()
      },{
          dc: $("#dcCode").val() ,
          question_Score : $("#102p").val() ,
          question_Desc: $("#103d").val(),
          "clinicAnalyzeQuestions.id" :102,
          "clinicAnalyzeQuestions.questions" : 'test2',
          "mobile" : $('#mobile').val(),
          "state" : $('#state').val()
      }];

                $.ajax({
                    url : "${insert}",
                    type : 'POST',
                    datatype : 'json',
                    data : JSON.stringify(jsonObjCommand) ,
                    success : function(data) {

                        var content = JSON.parse(data);         
                        $.each(content, function(i, state) {

                                $("#container2").hide();
                                $("#container").hide();
                                $("#frm1").hide();  
                                $('#success').show();
                                $('#userCount4').text(state.success);


                        });
                    }
                });
```

// controller

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "jsonObjCommand")
public List<ClinicAnalyzeAnswers> obtenerJsonObjCommand() {
    List<ClinicAnalyzeAnswers> jsonObjCommand = new ArrayList<ClinicAnalyzeAnswers>();
    System.out.println(jsonObjCommand.size());
    return jsonObjCommand;
}

@ModelAttribute("jsonObj1")
public ClinicPerson clinicPerson() {
    ClinicPerson person = new ClinicPerson();

    return person;
}

// @Transactional
@ResourceMapping("insert")
public void ajaxTestMethod(
        ResourceRequest request,
        ResourceResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "jsonObjCommand") List<ClinicAnalyzeAnswers> jsonObjCommand,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "jsonObj1") ClinicPerson person)
        throws IOException, ParseException {
    for (ClinicAnalyzeAnswers clinicAnalyzeAnswers : jsonObjCommand) {
        System.out.println(clinicAnalyzeAnswers.getDc()+"aaa");
    }
}
```

spring mvc [@ResourceMapping][1] get list of objects null in liferay spring MVC portlet????

in controller null [] array
help me.....

Comment: What /is/ the problem? Can you elaborate and explain your issue?

Comment: The data in controller is empty

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your ajax request, becouse in `ResourceMapping` method you don't receive `jsonObjCommand` nor `jsonObj1`

```
$.ajax({
    url : "${insert}",
    type : 'POST',
    datatype : 'json',
    data : {"jsonObjCommand" : JSON.stringify(jsonObjCommand)},
    success : function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I have changed but is null in controller